# How do I fix my SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  I have a table called "Tools" with the following columns [ID], [QtyOnHand], [SizeUS], [PlantID].  A typical small data sample may be something like this:

[image: Table]

I would like to group the data by size and have a column with a sum of qty grouped by each plant that would look something like this:

[image]

I tried the following query but it's not correct.

```
SELECT
     T.SizeUS
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(T.QtyOnHand) 
        From Tools T1
        WHERE T1.PlantID=1 AND T1.SizeUS=T.SizeUS
    ) As QtyPlant1
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(T.QtyOnHand)
        From Tools T2
        WHERE T2.PlantID=2 AND T2.SizeUS=T.SizeUS
    ) As QtyPlant2
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(T.QtyOnHand) 
        From Tools T5
        WHERE T5.PlantID=5 AND T5.SizeUS=T.SizeUS
    ) As QtyPlant5
FROM
    Tools T
GROUP BY
    T.SizeUS;
```

Comment: What database platform?

Comment: OldProgrammer: Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Erwin: I truly thought I did format it in a readable form.  My apologies. :)

Comment: David R: I really appreciate the edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  T.SizeUS, 
        , sum(case when T1.PlantID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as QtyPlant1
        , sum(case when T1.PlantID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as QtyPlant2
        , sum(case when T1.PlantID = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as QtyPlant5
FROM    Tools T
Group By T.SizeUS
```